# Make the camera go and return on the path?

Tags: camera, path

I would like to introduce a character by showing a round trip on a part of him to make like a gif. Anyway there's my problem/question :

How can I get the camera to go back and forth on the path ? like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following steps:

1. Create a path with the desired shape
2. Switch to *Edit Mode*, select all control points and duplicate them <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and unselect all
3. Border select the point were the *Camera* is supposed to turn around
4. Create a segment between the two select control points by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>
5. Add a *Follow Path* modifier to the camera, tick the *Follow Curve* checkbox
6. Press the *Animate Path* button in the modifier

With the two points being in the same place the camera turn will be very sudden, but I assume this is what you want, judging by your description.

Comment: Thank you also for your answer, the result isn't really what I want but it's a technique

Answer (score 1):

To do it you can:

- Put your camera on the center of the scene, give it a *Follow Path* constraint with the bezier curve as *Target*. Press the *Animate Path* button. In *Edit* mode, make sure that the curve goes in the right direction, if not press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.

[image]

- The *Animate Path* has automatically generated an animation along the curve but you can't make any change on it. So now you need to select your curve, go in the *Graph Editor*, select the *Evaluation Time* track, open the *Properties* panel on the right (<kbd>N</kbd>), press the *Modifier* tab and delete the *Generator*.

[image]

- Now the camera won't move anymore because you're supposed to generate its movement manually. Keep the curve selected, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Path Animation*. Now you will set the keyframes with the *Evaluation Time* value. For example at frame 1 put the value at 0, which means that the camera will be at the very beginning of the curve, and insert a keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image]

- At frame 50 put the *Evaluation Time* at 100 (which is the end of your curve as the *Frames* default value is 100) and insert a second keyframe with <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image]

- At frame 100 insert a third keyframe with an *Evaluation Time* of 0 to bring the camera back to the beginning of the curve.

[image]

- You can play with the *Graph Editor* curve to slow down or accelerate the camera movement.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your complete answer ! I failed somewhere I think ; When I click for play the animation the camera don't move anymore...

Comment: it won't move after you delete the Generator, it's normal, is it what you're talking about?

Comment: Nop, after set key manually thaht does'nt work. I restart it and the camera move but it's not going and back on the curve.  (just one way and not the way back)

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/